# how to add switch inside toolbar in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar

I am developing android app and I want to add `switch` inside `toolbar` it is not showing

below is my `xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Switch" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

following screen current ui

[image: current ui]

I want to know how to achieve that kind of ui what I have to do

Comment: add any layout inside toolbar and add switch inside that layout

Comment: Vivek I am already adding it

Comment: @VivekMishra can you check my xml

Comment: No its not implemented properly @sashabeliy

Comment: take relative layout in toolbar and inside that place switch

Comment: layout inside toolbar not toolbar inside layout

Comment: I guess he is using default toolbar already.

Comment: can you explain with coding sample I did not understand guys

Comment: @AfzalKhan can you explain with coding sample

Comment: can you post your java/kotlin code?

Answer (score 1):

Simply Change `AppTheme` to NoActionBar from `styles.xml`

styles.xml

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now run your app, switch will show on the top in Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom toolbar which you are already using in your xml file but you need to remove your default toolbar by calling `getSupportActionBar().hide();` in activity onCreate(). and set the color of toolbar in xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_large"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```